# How convert these characters?

Tags: javascript, react-native, character-encoding

I'm making a App in React that receive a specific html page and transform into a page in React, but when a put some string in a `<Text>` these characters are not converting:

[image]

The representation of `&#8212;` is `—`.

What these characters are called? Is there a way in React to convert these characters into their corresponding text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These symbols are called **HTML Symbol Entities**  Many mathematical,
>   technical, and currency symbols, are not present on a normal keyboard.
>
> If no entity name exists, you can use an entity number, a decimal, or
>   hexadecimal reference.

A Fast workaround for a single html entity that you know:

```
    <Text>
      {yourText.replace(/&#8212;/gi, '-')}
    </Text>
```

You could use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities) npm module to decode text before rendering:

**Example for multiple html entities**

```
const re = /&[^\s]*;/gi;
const allHtmlEntities = [];
while ((match = re.exec(youtText)) != null) {
  const htmlEntity = yourText.substring(match.index, 7);
  if (allHtmlEntities.indexOf(htmlEntity) === -1) {
    allHtmlEntities.push(htmlEntity);
  }
}

const entities = new Entities();

for (let i = 0; i < allHtmlEntities.length; i++) {
  const decodedValue = entities.decode(allHtmlEntities[i]);
  yourText = yourText.replace(new RegExp(allHtmlEntities[i], 'g'), decodedValue);
}
```

Comment: @Syed unfortunately, they're not interpreted automatically by `react-native` ... so I guess then we'd need some kind of `regex` to catch all these HTML SYMBOL ENTITES and use the npm I mentioned in the answer to convert it